# How to repeat background image AND scale the tiles to avoid tile cropping in Android

Tags: android, background, crop, repeat, tile

I want the background image to repeat as tiles, but to also scale to avoid cropping of tiles on the edges.

[image: Image tile cropping]

In the picture above, the background image tiles repeat, but the tiles on the edges get cropped. I would like to have the tiles scaled so there is no cropping. So, in the above picture, i would like 2 tiles horizontally and 2 tiles vertically, instead of 1.1 tiles horizontally and 1.7 tiles vertically.
Here's my code:

**app_background.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/exclusion"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@drawable/app_background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: make a custom `BitmapDrawable` class then